# Trying to create a startup manager using .net 2.0

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, startup

OK so I'm working on a integrated start-up manager with check boxes, so far this is what i have, it does this on form load:

```
RegistryKey hklm = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
foreach (string Programs in hklm.GetValueNames())
{
    string GetValue = hklm.GetValue(Programs).ToString();
    ListViewItem item1 = listView1.Items.Add(Programs);
    item1.SubItems.Add(hklm.Name.ToString().Replace("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion", "HKLM"));
    item1.SubItems.Add(GetValue);
}

RegistryKey hkcu = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
foreach (string Programs in hkcu.GetValueNames())
{
    string GetValue = hkcu.GetValue(Programs).ToString();
    ListViewItem item2 = listView1.Items.Add(Programs);
    item2.SubItems.Add(hkcu.Name.ToString().Replace("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion", "HKCU"));
    item2.SubItems.Add(GetValue);
}
```

i know its probably a bit sloppy but it seems to work. now what id like to know is, if i have check boxes enabled in the list view... how can i have it:

A: Check the ones that are "enabled"/not check the ones that are "Disabled"
B: make it so when you check one it "enables" it or uncheck one it "disables" it?

OR!

(preferred) make a context menu (right click menu) for disabling and re-enabling each entry (and disabling it would mean making a sub key called something like "Disabled Start" that it would move keys to and enabling them would move them back into the previous key)

i know for enabling/disabling you can just move the key to a different subkey for safe keeping, correct? or do i have this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you . and i world do this if i were you . :)

I think you can either store those disabled keys to a file stored in your app directory. you know , sth like ini file. or you can store them in the registry with a key created by yourself. so you can delete them when uninstalling the manager.

Answer (score 0):

Well the recommended procedure would be so actually save those entries into text files. I storngly suggest that you use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and even stronger if you are going to be building this for a network.

I dunno much about this but I think you could also export the entries into files (which could also be [IsolatedStorageFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx)) just like [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2005/09/30/55580.aspx) guy seems to have done (look for the "ExportKey" method) and then re-import them. Note that in this case you would still need to have some sort of mechanism to remember the entries so you can show them in the list view.

Regarding the context menu I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx) might be what you want, but I just actually google it and running Ubuntu so I can't really try it out before.